# Comparing differences of "be/get" and "will be/will get"

Tags: grammar, verbs

I'm not a native speaker of English. I would like to know if these sentences are correct and what their differences are. Thank you!

- Don't be confused with this matter.
- Don't get confused with this matter.
- Don't try to solve it, you will be confused.
- Don't try to solve it, you will get confused.

Answer (score 2):

The word **get** is used in your examples in the sense of **become**.

First, to be confused **with** something is an unusual expression. We are more often confused **by** or **about** a matter/issue/intention or whatever. However, it's perfectly grammatical.

Leaving this aside, there is very little distinction between the senses of **be** and **get** in your examples. For most purposes, they are interchangeable.

However, **get confused** implies a process of becoming confused over a period of time, whether minutes, hours or weeks, possibly as a person becomes more involved in a subject or issue.

**Be confused** simply states that the matter in question is confusing to someone without suggesting the process of becoming confused.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking about the comparison of "be" and "become" (the meaning of "get" in the two examples).

"Becoming" is the process something takes to "be": To become confused, I need to not be confused beforehand.